# Jackson ObjectMapper not able to recognize @JsonProperty Annotation

Tags: java, json, maven, jackson2

I am creating POJO's using jsonschema2pojo-maven-plugin, version 0.4.30. But when I use those pojo's in my code, Jackson ObjectMapper is not able to recognise @JsonProperty annotation. Below is the sample json:

```
{
  "title": "IP Address",
    "description": "Ip Address",
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
         "ip_address": {
             "type": "string",
             "minLength": 1,
             "maxLength": 39,
             "description": "ip address"
           }
    }
}
```

I have tried matching the jackson-databind versions, but it didn't worked.

```
@JsonInclude(Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({"ip_address"})
public class IpGeo {
    @JsonProperty("ip_address")
    @JsonPropertyDescription("ip address")
    @Size(
        min = 1,
        max = 39
    )
    private String ipAddress;
    @JsonProperty("ip_address")
    public String getIpAddress() {
        return this.ipAddress;
    }

    @JsonProperty("ip_address")
    public void setIpAddress(String ipAddress) {
        this.ipAddress = ipAddress;
    }
}
```

I expect ObjectMapper creates IpGeo class from the json. It should map ip_address to ipAddress. But it gives an error "ip_address field not recongnized".

Comment: Please, provide code how you deserialize json.

Comment: ipGeo = jsonMapper
       .readValue(new String(response.getValue()),
       IpGeo.class);

Comment: In your json sample I can't see string `ip_address` field. It's only the object `ip_address`.

Comment: ip_address is under properties:, that is the field ip_address.

Answer (score 0):

I found the issue in my code.
I had use JaxbAnnotationIntrospector that leverages JAXB annotations where applicable to JSON mapping.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had the same issue because I created an instance of ObjectMapper on my own instead of auto-wiring it. Here is the line in Kotlin:

```
@Autowired
lateinit var objectMapper: ObjectMapper
```